# WKWebView in ViewController presented with animation is cropped

Tags: ios, ipad, wkwebview

In my application I push a View Controller in a Navigation Controller with animation.

In it's viewDidLoad I load a local html. The problem is that this html is presented cropped, but if I start to scroll the web view, the html gets its correct size.

This is the code of the view controller, the viewDidLoad method.

```
@implementation WebViewController_iPad


 - (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSString *jScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=%d'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);", (int)self.mainContentView.frame.size.width];

        WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
        WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
        [wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

        WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;

        self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.mainContentView.bounds configuration:wkWebConfig];
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
        self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

        [self.mainContentView addSubview:self.webView];
        self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


        //WebView Contraints
        NSLayoutConstraint *topWebView =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

        NSLayoutConstraint *trailingWebView = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

        NSLayoutConstraint *leadingWebView = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

        //WebView and AdView related constraint s

        NSLayoutConstraint *bottomWebView = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.mainContentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

        //Add WebView constraints
        [self.mainContentView addConstraints:@[topWebView,trailingWebView,leadingWebView]];

        //WebView and AidView related constraints
        [self.mainContentView addConstraint:bottomWebView];


        NSString *finalArticalBody = @"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ultrices quis enim ut euismod. Aenean urna felis, aliquam sit amet facilisis id, commodo in ante. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque vehicula nisi nulla, sed mattis turpis dictum tincidunt. Nunc ornare ipsum lorem, vitae placerat odio tempus vel. Mauris suscipit lorem a odio aliquam, ac congue nibh venenatis. Fusce eu ipsum iaculis nisl pharetra lacinia. Aliquam id aliquet sapien. Aenean tellus magna, vehicula id dapibus et, hendrerit in enim. Praesent tristique turpis sed urna blandit scelerisque. Nam venenatis nisl sem, volutpat finibus leo ullamcorper eget.</p>";
       [self.webView loadHTMLString:finalArticalBody baseURL:nil];
}
```

The animation code is this:

```
[self addSubview:viewController.view];

    // set the frame to the right side of the last view controller
    viewController.frame = CGRectMake(topVC.frame.origin.x + topVC.frame.size.width, 0, viewController.view.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    if (animated)
    {
        // place off screen
        viewController.view.left = MAX(initialWidth, self.contentSize.width) + 51;
        viewController.view.height = self.frame.size.height;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:delay
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             viewController.view.left = self.contentSize.width + 50;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:kStackViewAnimationDuration
                                                   delay:0
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                              animations:^{
                                                  // place on the right side of the last view controller
                                                  viewController.view.frame = viewController.frame;
                                              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                  [self performAfterPush:viewController];
                                              }];
                         }];
    }
    else
    {
        // find the x offset to place this new view controller
        viewController.view.frame = viewController.frame;
        [self performAfterPush:viewController];
    }
```

I found out that if I set animation to false, the html gets the correct size since the beginning.

Also, If I animate the presentation and put a delay of 0.5 seconds in viewDidLoad to load the html, the html is properly sized.

Previously, I was using the deprecated class UIWebView and it doesn't have this problem.

What do I have to considerate to get the WKWebView html content properly sized?

The error looks like this :

[image]

If I scroll the web view, it gets its proper size.

[image]

Please help!!

Comment: Can you provide more detail and maybe an excerpt of your implementation? A lot of things can be the reason fro the cropping.

Comment: OK @palme, I will add more details in the post.

Comment: @palme I added snapshot of the code.